# Работа с объектами и null в Java

Tags: java, валидация, null, try-catch

Всем привет. Сейчас работаю надо валидацией полей и у меня может быть такое, что в поле `Integer` могут подать какой-нибудь `String abracadabra`. Мне бы хотелось чтобы при парсинге строки в `Integer` не срабатывало исключение, а просто к полю присваивалось значение `null`. Можно ли это как-то реализовать без `try catch`?

Если совсем просто: как мне парсить `String` в `Integer`, но без вылавливания `Exception`?

Comment: Посмотреть на что нибудь такое tryParse

Comment: А чем Вас try/catch(NumberFormatException) не устраивает?

Comment: @Sergi их выходит очень много и код становится страшным.

Comment: @MaksimMatantsev, у вас будет один метод с `try/catch`, который возвращает значение `Integer`. Везде, где нужно, вы его просто вызываете. Откуда здесь *много*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть ещё такой вариант

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tmp = "abcd";
        tmp = tmp.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        Integer needed;

        if(tmp.isBlank()){
            needed = null;
        }else{
            needed = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
        }

        System.out.println(needed);
    }
```

Убираем всё, кроме чисел и смотрим, осталось ли что-нибудь

Comment: вы заменяете только буквы, а не *всё, кроме чисел*

Comment: @ThePrettyFace, могут быть не только буквы, а вообще любые символы

Comment: Да, вы правы, нужно добавить в regex дополнительные свойства для удаления доп символов таких как - "*,./" и другие

Comment: Сейчас подумаю..

Comment: Окей, поменял на tmp = tmp.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""); Это удалит все символы кроме цифр

Comment: Было бы хорошо еще в алгоритме сверять строки на длину (первоначальное значение и после парсинга), а то получается ,что если пользователь введет `#$@123123fgr` вы запишете `123123`. Если это существенно, конечно, в вашем случае

Comment: Вот я тоже не уверен, существенно это или нет, в вопросе не было указано, так же возможен такой случай - `a2b89adasd897`. Тоже не известно, автор хочет получить `2` или `289897`

Comment: Если будет сочетание символов и цифр, то в этом случае должен быть null, а не оставшиеся цифры при удалении символов

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ написать подобную статическую функцию

```
@Nulluble
static Integer tryParseInt(String value) { 
 try {  
     return Integer.parseInt(value);  
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {  
      // Log exception.
      return null;
  }  
}
```

Если вы хотите больше заморочиться, то можно найти в Kotlin-e экстеншен функцию [String.toIntOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html) и переписать ее на статический метода в Java

```
public fun String.toIntOrNull(radix: Int): Int? {
    checkRadix(radix)

    val length = this.length
    if (length == 0) return null

    val start: Int
    val isNegative: Boolean
    val limit: Int

    val firstChar = this[0]
    if (firstChar < '0') {  // Possible leading sign
        if (length == 1) return null  // non-digit (possible sign) only, no digits after

        start = 1

        if (firstChar == '-') {
            isNegative = true
            limit = Int.MIN_VALUE
        } else if (firstChar == '+') {
            isNegative = false
            limit = -Int.MAX_VALUE
        } else
            return null
    } else {
        start = 0
        isNegative = false
        limit = -Int.MAX_VALUE
    }


    val limitForMaxRadix = (-Int.MAX_VALUE) / 36

    var limitBeforeMul = limitForMaxRadix
    var result = 0
    for (i in start until length) {
        val digit = digitOf(this[i], radix)

        if (digit < 0) return null
        if (result < limitBeforeMul) {
            if (limitBeforeMul == limitForMaxRadix) {
                limitBeforeMul = limit / radix

                if (result < limitBeforeMul) {
                    return null
                }
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }

        result *= radix

        if (result < limit + digit) return null

        result -= digit
    }

    return if (isNegative) result else -result
}
```